# Presto SQL query to calcute percent views

Tags: sql, presto

I have to calculate % contribution for each category.

[image]

```
SELECT portfolio, (total_portfolio_views*1.00000/total_views)*100 view_contribution_perc
FROM(
select portfolio,sum(portfolio_views) AS total_portfolio_views, (select sum(portfolio_views) from gold.user_daily_osv) as total_views
from gold.user_daily_osv
group by 1
)
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

Although this works fine, but it takes a lot of time to execute since these are huge tables, any other workaround for the same would be highly helpful.

Comment: Redshift and presto are different sql engines. Which one do you use?

Comment: @GuruStron I use Presto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `sum` [window function](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/window.html) to compute total views on the aggregate:

```sql
SELECT portfolio,
    (total_portfolio_views * 1.0 / sum(total_portfolio_views) over ()) * 100 view_contribution_perc
FROM(
        select portfolio,
            sum(portfolio_views) AS total_portfolio_views
        from gold.user_daily_osv
        group by 1
    )
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```